# Ruby: Parsing a complex hash

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that goes multiple levels deep: http://gist.github.com/285350

I am trying to loop through each serving but I keep running into multiple nil[] errors even though the hash isn't nil.

For example:

```
food_hash["food"]["servings"]
```

Returns nil.[]

It might be because im half asleep but I can't seem to get down to the "serving_description"... could anyone help put me in the right direction?

Comment: Should I just assume that your missing double-quote is an error in copying and does not exist in your actual code? See your one-liner provided in the question.

Comment: I don't see the key "food" anywhere in that gist.

Comment: Matchu: fixed, thanks
Ben: sorry I stipped out some of the hash because it was really long.

It actually begins with {"food"=>{"food_name"=>"Bacon"...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't see get down to the "serving_description"

Note that (1) `servings.serving` is an array, and (2) `food` is not a key in the hash. Try this instead:

```
f["servings"]["serving"][0]["serving_description"]
=> "1 thin slice (yield after cooking)"
```

where `f` is the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
food_hash["servings"]["serving"][0]["serving_description"]
```